# Jetifier, androidx and issues when verify if can keep Android Jetifier disabled

Tags: android, react-native, androidx, react-native-reanimated

I'm migrating from Jeitifier to Androidx and I found a strange error. I research everywhere and I'm really not sure if there is something to do or just ignore and disable Jeitifier.
For testing, if I can drop Jeitifier I'm using [bye-bye-jetifier](https://github.com/dipien/bye-bye-jetifier)
but this return me:

```
Project: :react-native-reanimated
=========================================
[WARN] The file 'com/android/SdkConstants.class' contains a string literal with a package reference 'android.support.design.widget'. Libraries using reflection such as annotation processors need to be updated manually to add support for androidx. But if you are sure there is no need to transform this package reference you can ignore this message or exclude this file from scanning using the 'excludedFilesFromScanning' property.

Scanning com.android.tools.ddms:ddmlib:30.3.1
 Absolute path: /Users/darek/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools.ddms/ddmlib/30.3.1/f271cb990dc62f580b608a75c87c509683c75da9/ddmlib-30.3.1.jar
 Graphs to this dependency:
 +---com.android.tools.utp:android-device-provider-ddmlib:30.3.1
     +---com.android.tools.ddms:ddmlib:30.3.1
 Issues found:
 * com/android/ddmlib/testrunner/AndroidTestOrchestratorRemoteAndroidTestRunner.class -> android.support.test.services.
 * com/android/ddmlib/testrunner/AndroidTestOrchestratorRemoteAndroidTestRunner.class -> android.support.test.services.shellexecutor.
 * com/android/ddmlib/testrunner/AndroidTestOrchestratorRemoteAndroidTestRunner.class -> android.support.test.orchestrator.

Scanning com.android.tools:common:30.3.1
 Absolute path: /Users/darek/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools/common/30.3.1/6d00d4eaf6e80712b579a71e50f574483e6aef31/common-30.3.1.jar
 Graphs to this dependency:
 +---com.android.tools.utp:android-device-provider-ddmlib:30.3.1
     +---com.android.tools:common:30.3.1
 +---com.android.tools.utp:android-device-provider-ddmlib:30.3.1
     +---com.android.tools.ddms:ddmlib:30.3.1
          +---com.android.tools:common:30.3.1
 +---com.android.tools.utp:android-device-provider-gradle:30.3.1
     +---com.android.tools:common:30.3.1
 +---com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-host-additional-test-output:30.3.1
     +---com.android.tools:common:30.3.1
 +---com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-host-coverage:30.3.1
     +---com.android.tools:common:30.3.1
 +---com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-host-device-info:30.3.1
     +---com.android.tools:common:30.3.1
 +---com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-host-logcat:30.3.1
     +---com.android.tools:common:30.3.1
 +---com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-host-retention:30.3.1
     +---com.android.tools:common:30.3.1
 +---com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-result-listener-gradle:30.3.1
     +---com.android.tools:common:30.3.1
 Issues found:
 * com/android/SdkConstants$PreferenceAndroidX.class -> android.support.v7.preference.
 * com/android/SdkConstants.class -> android.support.v4.view.ActionProvider
 * com/android/SdkConstants.class -> android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
 * com/android/SdkConstants.class -> android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout
 * com/android/SdkConstants.class -> android.support.v4.
 * com/android/SdkConstants.class -> android.support.v7.
 * com/android/SdkConstants.class -> android.support.design.
 * com/android/SdkConstants.class -> android.support.constraint.
 * com/android/SdkConstants.class -> android.support.v17.leanback.
 * com/android/SdkConstants.class -> android.support.v4.app.
 * com/android/SdkConstants.class -> android.support.v7.app.
 * com/android/SdkConstants.class -> android.support.v4.widget.
 * com/android/SdkConstants.class -> android.support.v4.view.
 * com/android/SdkConstants.class -> android.support.v7.widget.
 * com/android/SdkConstants.class -> android.support.v17.leanback.app.
 * com/android/SdkConstants.class -> android.support.multidex.
 * com/android/SdkConstants.class -> android.support.design.widget.
 * com/android/SdkConstants.class -> android.support.constraint.motion.
 * com/android/SdkConstants.class -> android.support.constraint.helper.
 * com/android/SdkConstants.class -> android.support.constraint.utils.
 * com/android/SdkConstants.class -> android.databinding.
 * com/android/SdkConstants.class -> android.arch.lifecycle.
 * com/android/support/AndroidxName.class -> android.databinding.
 * com/android/support/AndroidxNameUtils.class -> android.databinding.
```

My versions:

"react-native": "0.71.8",

"react-native-reanimated": "3.2.0",

---

Really appreciate any help. Thanks :)